# function return value of the newest member

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm trying to create my first function with the following example:

```
function getNumMembers(){

    if($this->num_members < 0) {
        $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS;
        $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
        $this->num_members = mysql_numrows($result);
    }

    return $this->num_members;
}
```

Now I want to get the latest member out of the database and created this:

```
function getNewestMember(){
    $q = "SELECT LAST(username) FROM ".TBL_USERS;
    $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
}
```

But because this only results of the latest username, I have no idea how I should show that, any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you getting problem of giving an alias. Give an alias to your column like this: `"SELECT LAST(username) as last_username FROM ".TBL_USERS`.

Comment: do You have any primary key or unique id in table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any Primary Key or [Unique key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) or [Candidate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key) and like **ID**

use this query

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Or another option is this you can store create_date as TimeStamp

```
Alter table ".TBL_USERS." add created_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

**This is how you can show Lastest_username now:**

```
function getNewestMember(){
    $q = "SELECT user_name FROM ".TBL_USERS." ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['user_name'];
}
//calling now function
echo($this->getNewestMember());//if i working with objects
echo(getNewestMember());//if i working normally
```

> **Note:** Mysql is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php)  use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for prevent from sql
>   Injection also.

Comment: Done but how do i echo the latest member now? because it still says  nothing when i called it in the footer.

Comment: `Warning: Illegal string offset 'username' in` on the line of return $row. Also i edited the user_name to username idk if that has to do something with it

Comment: I fixed it by changing `return $row[0]['username'];` to `return $row['username'];`

Answer (score 0):

try if you have autoincrement field

```
$q = "SELECT username FROM ".TBL_USERS." ORDER BY autoincrement_field DESC LIMIT 1;
```

if you not have any primary key then need two queries

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable;  //counting all rows
SELECT * FROM yourTable LIMIT useCountHere - 1,1;  // give you last row
```

Comment: i do not have a auto increment field,

Answer (score 0):

First, do not build anything with mysql_query -- you should be using mysqli.

Next, if this is your first function, why are you calling properties on $this? Is this a class method or a function? If it's a class method, then you should also explicity set visibility to public/private/protected.

Next, is TBL_USERS a constant?

Comment: To be honest this is my first function O.O

Answer (score 0):

Try this query for Selecting the last row.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

NOTE : Provided you should have an unique ID field in the table.